# Converting to dalvik format failed when I try to add external Jars

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using Zend Studio 7.2 as my main IDE. I develope android apps. I wanted to work with html parsers, however adding external jars I get always the same problem **Converting to dalvik format failed** and eclipse needs a lot of time to build workspace.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved the problem, here a useful link
[link text](http://www.cuteandroid.com/tips-for-android-developer-conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-unable-to-execute-dex-null)

following steps helped

1. Right-click the project in Eclipse and select “Build Path -> Add Libraries…”.
2. Select User Library from the list and click Next.
3. Click the “User Libraries…” button.
4. Click “New…” in the User Libraries dialog.
5. Give the user library a name and select the System library checkbox and click OK.
6. Highlight the newly added user library in the list and click the “Add JARs…” button and add the desired jar files.
7. Click OK on the User Libraries dialog.
8. Make sure the new user library is checked in the Add Library dialog and …

Comment: You may want to accept your own answer. That gives you a badge and prevents this question from showing up as "unanswered".

Comment: stackoverflow says I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer. Saved me time figuring out the solution.