# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 with HTML Parser

Tags: android, html-parsing

is it the problem that android jre does not support html parser???!!!

Comment: 1. We need more information - what exactly are you trying to do, what class/jar are you trying to use?
2. Try not to use multiple punctuation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what the real issue is, this post might help: [Converting to dalvik format failed when I try to add external Jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542092/converting-to-dalvik-format-failed-when-i-try-to-add-external-jars)